# [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte in Spark scala streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming

I am trying to convert DStream[Array[Byte]] to DStream[String] but getting error as : [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte with following code.

```
val data = KafkaUtils.CreateDirectStream(ssc,kafkaConf,Map(topic,1).map(bytes => bytes._2.toString)
```

data is of type DStream[String] but its giving me above error while running the code.

Could any one help me on how to convert DStream[Array[Byte]] to DStream[String]

I tried couple of things like converting bytes => new String(bytes) but it saying String in not a valid constructor.

Thanks

Comment: what's your `kafkaConf` like? Also your above code snippet is a bit broken.

Comment: I fixed myself changing kafstream by passing StringDecoder instead DefaultDecoder and issue got fixed. thanks for your reply..